# calculate work time between two times in python

Tags: python

i have two Datetimes for worker ( start work time , end work time) . im just trying to subtract the end work time from start work time

```
starttime = "23:51:26"
endtime = "04:10:11"

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(endtime, FMT) - datetime.strptime(starttime, FMT)

print(tdelta)
```

**Result**
`-1 day, 4:18:45`

I want the result to be `4:18:45`
any help ? thanks

Answer (score -3):

Here your snippet!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
starttime = "04:10:11"
endtime = "23:51:26"
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
t1 = datetime.strptime(starttime, FMT)
t2 = datetime.strptime(endtime, FMT)
tdelta = (t1 - t2) * (1 - 2 * (t1 < t2))
print(tdelta)
```

Comment: what is the result in case: `starttime = "04:10:11"` and `endtime = "23:51:26"`? Not sure your snippet is too helpful in this case :)

Comment: Yes, i have changed it @CornelRaiu